# browse ftp folder with QFileDialog

Tags: qt

I want to use **QFileDialog** to browse network shared folder over ftp. But it opens local file dialog rather than ftp dialog. My code below:

```
QUrl url = QUrl("ftp//10.0.0.3:21");
QUrl file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl(this,tr("Select File"),url,"img(*.tiff *.tif *.txt *)");
```

Why this?

Comment: That URL should be `ftp://` not `ftp//`.

Comment: I'm sorry to write a wrong url when ask. But url is right in my project.

Comment: Does specifying the [`supportedSchemes`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileUrl) parameter help at all?

Comment: @G.M. I tried, but made no progress.

Answer (score 1):

Like " MrEricSir", you have to give `ftp://`.

To set up a ftp URL call below function before passing the URL to `QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl`

```
QUrl::setScheme(const QString &scheme)
```

The below documentation link has an example explaining and how to set the scheme.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#setScheme

```
QUrl url = QUrl("ftp://10.0.0.3:21");
url.setScheme("ftp");
```

Comment: I'm sorry to write a wrong URL when ask. But URL is right in my project. So this can't help. Do I have any other solutions? Thx.

Comment: Did you try setScheme which I put in answer

Comment: Yes, I tried. I added `url.setScheme("ftp");`. This doesn't work. In my console, it reminded me `QWindowsNativeFileDialogBase::shellItem : Unhandled scheme:  "ftp"`.